# Load a page with javascript/html5 on SSH

Tags: php, javascript, python, html, ssh

Previously, I was working in Python using the Spynner module to macro through browsing specific webpages for me until I ran in to one page where Spynner could not correctly run the javascript on the website. I was unable to find another Python module that supported Javascript in a browser, so I moved on to trying new methods.

I have access to my Hostgator SSH as well as one of those "free" ssh server. Would there be a command through SSH I could execute that would load a webpages javascript and HTML5 coding fully on the SSH server? (Being able to view it is not reqired). I was thinking of maybe running a PHP command? Or would something else work better?

Any help is apprcieated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). It has a great scripting engine to interact with pages that are downloaded. This assumes you actually want the HTML and javascript to be rendered as if it was loaded in a browser rather than just downloading the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Selenium. Selenium supports javascript
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium